# Passing parameters to a4j:ajax method

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, ajax4jsf

I am trying to use `<a4j:ajax>` to feed a method with a value just entered on the form;

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="aa" value="#{colorClass.color}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{myChoices.colorOptions}"/>
    <a4j:ajax event="change" render="colorCode" 
        execute="#{myChoices.getColorCode(colorClass,colorClass.color)}"/>
</selectOneMenu>
```

Color on the form is selected correctly;

my problem is that when I pass `colorClass.color` as part of the execute, it is blank;
if I replace `colorClass.color` with a literal

```
<a4j:ajax event="change" render="colorCode" 
    execute="#{myChoices.getColorCode(colorClass,'green')}"/>
```

the method is called, finds the colorCode and repaints the form

How can I "grab" the value just entered so that I can pass it as a parameter to the method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `listener` attribute instead of `execute` attribute. The `execute` attribute should point to a collection of client IDs which are to be submitted (which defaults to `@this` in `<f:ajax>` and `@form` in `<a4j:ajax>`). However in your particular case it returns `void` and keeps the `execute` empty. The `listener` attribute is supposed to point to a bean action listener method. Fix it accordingly:

```
<a4j:ajax event="change" render="colorCode" 
    listener="#{myChoices.getColorCode(colorClass,colorClass.color)}"/>
```

Note that the `colorClass` argument seems superfluous here, or at least the `colorClass.color` as you could also just do `colorClass.getColor()` inside the `getColorCode()` method. Just passing one of them ought to be sufficient. Passing `colorClass.color` would be preferable so that your `myChoices` bean is not tight coupled with the `colorCode` bean.

```
<a4j:ajax event="change" render="colorCode" 
    listener="#{myChoices.getColorCode(colorClass.color)}"/>
```